# How can I remove gum from carpet?

Tags: home, cleaning

Sometimes, chewing gum inevitably gets on the carpet. How do I get it back off?

I've tried using ice to harden the gum, and lifting it off, but it didn't freeze down far enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends a bit on the type of carpet you have, but for 'non-fluffy' carpets I can recommend using ice-spray to freeze the gum. It gets porous and you can vacuum it off easily. I have not tested this on long fibre carpets.

You should be able to get the spray at an apothecary or the right convenience store

Comment: Alternatively, you can take the computer compressed air, invert the can, and spray that. Same effect.

Answer (score 2):

Use a blow drier to start softening the gum. Use a scoop to scoop up the gum. If the gub is stubborn, keep on heating it. Eventually it will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You could scrub it hard with a combination of water and soap or bleach with an old toothbrush. Maybe the bleach will affect the colors of the carpet, so this might not work in your case.

Comment: Scrubbing hard, irrespective of whether you use soap, bleach or anything else, will wreck your carpet.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that any scrubbing will ruin it.