# Removing chewing gum from car Mat

Tags: cleaning

Today someone stick chewing gum to the floor mat of my car. It look pretty badZ how can I remove it? I m trying to freeze it with ice packs and then remove it but it is not helping
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to freeze it by placing the ice packs around the spot? That won’t work, you need to at minimum place the packs directly on the spot, better yet, place the mat in your freezer (wrapping it would be a good idea for hygienic reasons).

Comment: The makers of WD-40 [claim](https://wd40.co.uk/how-to/how-to-get-chewing-gum-out-of-carpet/) that its users have removed chewing gum from a carpet with it, but "These uses haven’t been tested by WD-40 Company and do not constitute a recommendation of suggestion for use by WD-40 Company." Of course, you'll use their product! And there remains the need to remove the WD-40 which is now saturating the carpet, and has a distinctive odour.

Comment: Related (and possibly helpful): https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/6336/how-to-get-gum-off-of-clothes

Answer (score 0):

Remove the mat from the car.

Put it in deep freeze for an hour.  (-18 F  0 C)

Get ready:

You want a short radius corner to wrap around.

You want to bend the mat itself in a sharp bend.  A chunk of flat iron bar sock clamped upright would be great.  Try over the edge of your freezer.

If this doesn't work  you need to be more brittle:  Chill it with dry ice.  Caution:  Burn hazard.

Once it's brittle, run under it with a kitchen fork.

Refreeze if you need to and get the last with a slicker brush (fine wire dog brush)